# Webservice response with nullable doubles is not deserialized properly

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization, double, nullable

I'm calling a webservice from one of our partners. I have no problem calling it and I get a result.
The response has nullable doubles. In fiddler I see in the XML of the response these doubles have values, but somehow these fields do not get deserialized to my proxy class because these fields have the value null there.

This is a summary of the response xml I get, somehow the value in id27 does not get serialized, but the boolean in id26 does.  Why?

```
<extras soapenc:arrayType="ns2:Extra[16]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
    <extras href="#id1"/>
    <extras href="#id2"/>           
    ...
</extras>
...
<multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" 
soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xsi:type="ns6:Extra" xmlns:ns6="http://model.bookingservice.app.traserv.com" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <assignments xsi:type="ns6:Assignment" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <category xsi:type="xsd:string">def_Surety</category>           
    ...
    <orderUnit xsi:type="xsd:string">Verblijf</orderUnit>
    <payAtLocation href="#id26"/>
    <price href="#id27"/>
    <priceNotes xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
     ...
</multiRef>
...
<multiRef id="id26" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xsi:type="xsd:boolean" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">true</multiRef>
<multiRef id="id27" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="xsd:double" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">345.0</multiRef>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found WCF clients and axis webservice do have these problems.
You can solve it in the proxy, which is obviously not nice because you have to edit generated classes. Or you can change the webservice, which is also a problem because you have not always  control over that one.

Anyway I found these items about it:
http://www.tomergabel.com/GettingWCFAndApacheAxisToBeFriendly.aspx

[Why won't .NET deserialize my primitive array from a web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171/why-wont-net-deserialize-my-primitive-array-from-a-web-service)