# WCF XML deserialization fail

Tags: c#, wcf

I've got this WSDL(the service is not mine): http://soaptest.webapi-beta.gratka.pl/dom.html?wsdl

When I get response from method "pobierz_kategorie" I get exception like that

CommunicationException
Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'pobierz_kategorie'.
{"There is an error in XML document (2, 501)."} {"The specified type was not recognized: name='kategoria_drzewo', namespace='http://soap.webapi-beta.gratka.pl/dom.html', at ."}

I would like to ask how to modify WSDL or WCF configuration or generated proxy to make it working. When I use PHP to call that method it works so I guess that must be some XMLSerializer problem.

This the response message I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://soap.webapi-beta.gratka.pl/dom.html" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:pobierz_kategorieResponse>
            <drzewo_kategorii SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:kategoria_drzewo[48]" xsi:type="ns1:drzewo_kategorii">
                <item xsi:type="ns1:kategoria_drzewo">
                    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">382</id>
                    <nazwa xsi:type="xsd:string">Dom</nazwa>
                    <dane xsi:type="xsd:string">0</dane>
                    <id_rodzic xsi:type="xsd:int">1</id_rodzic>
                    <poziom xsi:type="xsd:int">0</poziom>
                    <id_prasa xsi:type="xsd:int">2</id_prasa>
                </item>
                <item xsi:type="ns1:kategoria_drzewo">
                    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">8251</id>
                    <nazwa xsi:type="xsd:string">Pokoje</nazwa>
                    <dane xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                    <id_rodzic xsi:type="xsd:int">382</id_rodzic>
                    <poziom xsi:type="xsd:int">1</poziom>
                    <id_prasa xsi:type="xsd:int">0</id_prasa>
                </item>
            </drzewo_kategorii>
        </ns1:pobierz_kategorieResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

That is the request:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:q1="http://soaptest.webapi-beta.gratka.pl/dom.html">
    <s:Body s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <q1:pobierz_kategorie>
            <sesja xsi:type="xsd:string">ad9e730460e334b916c95533c8da320003ac7e14</sesja>
            <id_kategoria xsi:type="xsd:int">382</id_kategoria>
        </q1:pobierz_kategorie>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: @user1121956 can you post the request as well

Comment: @NickRyan I added request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've retrieved that WSDL and the response message name does not match what you have above.
Where you have `pobierz_kategorieResponse` in the wsdl, it is `pobierz_kategorie_wyjscie` in the WSDL definition.

*Message*...

```
  <message name="pobierz_kategorie_wyjscie">
    <part name="drzewo_kategorii" type="tns:drzewo_kategorii"/>
  </message>
```

*Operation*...

```
<operation name="pobierz_kategorie">
  <input message="tns:pobierz_kategorie_wejscie"/>
  <output message="tns:pobierz_kategorie_wyjscie"/>
</operation>
```

Maybe you need to regenerate your service reference or point it at a different endpoint.

**EDIT**

You may have to customize your reference.cs file (your generated WCF client code) to handle the soap array. I haven't done this myself but there is an SO article about it:-
[Why won't .NET deserialize my primitive array from a web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171/why-wont-net-deserialize-my-primitive-array-from-a-web-service)
I'm not 100% sure if this is the same issue as what you are having. It looks like you need to tell WCF explicitly - for this element, this is how you de-serialize the array. Sorry I can't be of more help.

**EDIT #2**
There is a mismatch between the wsdl published to you 'soaptest' and the actual implementation. Note the namespaces. Or, you've generated your code of a test wsdl endpoint and pointed it at a prod endpoint.See the namespaces below.
Your request's namespaces looked like this:-

- http://soaptest.webapi-beta.gratka.pl/dom.html

But the response's namespaces looked like this:-

- http://soap.webapi-beta.gratka.pl/dom.html

That ain't gonna work!

Try generating your WCF client off

- http://soap.webapi-beta.gratka.pl/dom.html?wsdl

instead of off

- http://soaptest.webapi-beta.gratka.pl/dom.html?wsdl

Comment: Actually I have no knowledge about WSDL but you're right it's weird that reponse from server generates tag with "Response" word if there is not such thing in WSDL. Is it possible WSDL is not matching with real web-service code?

Comment: OMG, it's working! As you suggested theirs implementation from test server points to WSDL from production server so namespaces doesn't fit. Thank you very much!

Comment: btw. do you have any idea how is that possible that "wejscie/wyjscie" is changed to Request/Response words? it is some magic or just normal WS-* behaviour?

Comment: @user1121956 no I don't know why that is happening. Not normal as far as I can tell. Anyway, you're up and running. Happy coding!